# Define an object that implements a generic interface

Tags: typescript

I want to define an object that implements some generic interface with some properties that are not in the interface, like this:

```js
type TaskType = "build" | "harvest";

class Task<T extends TaskType> {
    constructor(public type: T) { }
}

interface Action<T extends TaskType> {
    from(task: Task<T>): number;
    to(task: Task<T>): number;
}

const defineAction = <T extends TaskType, U extends Action<T>>(obj: U): Action<T> => obj;

const HarvestAction: Action<"harvest"> = defineAction({
    check(task: Task<"harvest">): boolean { return Math.random() > 0.5; },
    to(task) { return 0; },
    from(task) {
        this.check(task); // OK
        this.to(task); // OK
        return this.check(task) ? 0 : this.to(task); // Error here
    },
});
```

But as you can see, in the return statement, the editors (vscode and tsplay) don't seem to understand the type of `this` correctly. Or it could, because I see when I hover over `this` that the editor does know its type. Anyway, I successfully compiled these codes with `tsc` without any warnings and errors. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug that needs to be fixed?

Comment: Why are you writing `if (this.check(num))` when `check()` returns `void`?  Seems like an error unrelated to your question; could you fix your code so that the only problem is the one you're asking about?  Please review the guidelines for what constitutes a [mre].

Comment: If I change your `check()` return to `boolean`, then you can do what you want [in several ways](https://tsplay.dev/m3yb2w).  When you say "Typescript doesn't allow to define properties that are not in an interface", you are presumably talking about [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks), but those only happen in particular situations and are intended to be circumventable.  If you really want to define an anonymous class and immediately get its instance you can.

Comment: Which, if any (or all), of [these approaches](https://tsplay.dev/m3yb2w) would you like to see as an answer?  Or are they all inappropriate and I'm missing something about your question?

Comment: Oh, that was my little mistake. The last one looks like the anonymous class I want, but I still need to specify that the `num` parameter of the `calc` function is of type `number`, which is what I want to avoid by defining an interface. So I choose the second answer. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I ran into a [new problem](https://tsplay.dev/WYko3N) while using your solution, in fact the interface to be implemented in my project is a generic interface.

Comment: Either it really is a new problem in which case it is out of scope here, or it is an unstated requirement of your original question in which case you should [edit] to make your example a [mre] that demonstrates it.  Which one is it?  (One might address that new issue like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvEvkm), but for Stack Overflow we need this post to be a single well-defined question, in order for it to be answerable.)